# Software Automation tool

Tags: automation

At my company, we have to fill out a daily timecard, and I want to automate it.
I want to use some sort of tool that will allow me to write something like this:

```
Launch Firefox
go to www.example.com/timecard
Wait for page load complete
In UserName box: put username
In Password box: put password 
Press enter

Wait for page load complete

if login failed
   email me@example.com that unable to automatically do timecard, please check password
   return;

Get today's date

if today is Saturday or Sunday
  close firefox
  return;


find the timecard column that matches today's date
find the row with the right charge number
put in 8.0 hours
click "Save" link
close firefox
return;
```

It would be really nice if the software solution will also execute itself daily at a given time.

Comment: There are so many ways to do this as to make the question menaingless imo. Better would be for you to choose a technology that you want to learn, then verify that it has the capability to do what you want. Then try to do it and post questions when you have problems.

Comment: You should rename your question and replace "software" with "user interface"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to automatize is related to browsers, then you may try out [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/) which provides libraries in different languages.

For browser automation, there are a couple more experimental libraries in javascript (you should search for web app testing tools as these are imo your best bet for now)

./alex

Answer (score 4):

Since you are asking about UI automation you might want to check out [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

It's a macro language and you can compile the code into executable binaries (.exe).

However, sending web request could be done better without a browser by sending the necessary HTTP requests. Such an approach is more light-weight, more flexible and probably easier to maintain as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/) extension for Firefox.  I believe it may help you a long the way.

> Chickenfoot is a Firefox extension that puts a programming environment in the browser's sidebar so you can write scripts to manipulate web pages and automate web browsing.

It also provides a basic record feature, and you can then fine-tune the interactiosn with the web page(s).

Answer (score 1):

For decision making, you might have to write some code.

[iMacros for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863) has the ability to record/playback.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it myself but I have heard good things about [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). This is a Web UI testing tool that can be scripted in a number of different languages.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to accomplish this with [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If by "some sort of tool" do you mean something like a programming language or environment that will allow you to automate what FireFox does? If so, I recommend learning how to write a FireFox extension. Extensions are written in Javascript.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions

--
bmb

Answer (score 0):

You could use selenium or watin on a simple .net console program. Then configure a task on window to call it at a given time of day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux you could easily do this with a bash script of some kind. Have a look at the CURL library.http://curl.haxx.se/. You could then schedule the script to run with cron.

This is why I love Linux, the above is simple to do. I windows I suppose you could use the windows shell. I think the curl library runs on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium (www.openqa.org) tools will work for you.  Install the Selenium IDE and record the macro.  The "code" is simple JavaScript/HTML.

Selenium RC provides a very strong solution for automated testing from a variety of languages and tools.